# SQL Server - Update table based in data sequence and product code

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a table `ProductViewOccurences` that contains previous data in column `ProductCode` and `FirstOccurrenceData`. The columns `ProductCodeOccurence` and `SecondOccurenceData` must be updated with data from second table `ProductSecondHit`.

`ProductViewOccurences` before update

```
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| ProductCode |   FirstOccurenceDate    | ProductCodeOccurence | SecondOccurenceDate |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|    01259853 | 2020-03-06 15:35:49.813 |                      |                     |
|    01259853 | 2020-03-06 22:48:11.207 |                      |                     |
|    01259853 | 2020-03-09 15:34:54.780 |                      |                     |
|    03589549 | 2020-03-12 11:05:39.108 |                      |                     |
|    03589549 | 2020-03-12 17:12:52.136 |                      |                     |
|    03589549 | 2020-03-13 14:21:54.241 |                      |                     |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

This is the second table - `ProductSecondHit`:

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| ProductCodeOccurence  |   SecondOccurenceDate   |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|              01259853 | 2020-03-06 18:03:53.023 |
|              01259853 | 2020-03-11 05:06:25.563 |
|              03589549 | 2020-03-12 14:26:53.652 |
|              03589549 | 2020-03-13 13:38:23.120 |
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
```

`ProductViewOccurences` should look like this after update (expected):

```
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
| ProductCode |   FirstOccurenceDate    | ProductCodeOccurence |   SecondOccurenceDate   |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
|    01259853 | 2020-03-06 15:35:49.813 |             01259853 | 2020-03-06 18:03:53.023 |
|    01259853 | 2020-03-06 22:48:11.207 |                      |                         |
|    01259853 | 2020-03-09 15:34:54.780 |             01259853 | 2020-03-11 05:06:25.563 |
|    03589549 | 2020-03-12 11:05:39.108 |             03589549 | 2020-03-12 14:26:53.652 |
|    03589549 | 2020-03-12 17:12:52.136 |             03589549 | 2020-03-13 13:38:23.120 |
|    03589549 | 2020-03-13 14:21:54.241 |                      |                         |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+
```

I've tried to use `MAX` and `MIN` date in `SELECT` with `OVER (PARTITION BY)` to get the interval between `FirstOcurrenceDate` column by `ProductCode` to update, but without success.

The business rules for the update are:

1. If the second occurrence date is between product code first occurrence date;
2. If the second occurrence date is greater than all code first occurrence date, the last line of product code first occurrence date need to be updated.

To turn more simple to understand:

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
|  Fuit    | FirstSequence | ConfirmFruit | SecondSequence |
+----------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| Apple    |             1 | Apple        |              2 |
| Apple    |             3 | Apple        |              5 |
| Apple    |             6 | Apple        |             33 |
| Orange   |             1 |              |                |
| Orange   |             2 | Orange       |              9 |
+----------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You should include in your question what you have tried and also explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '2020/03/21', '2020/03/15');
```

The interval can be:
second, minute, hour, dayofyear ETC